# PS3 freezing between 10-60 minutes after system start only on games, audio persists

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

I have an old 60gig PS3 that is crashing in games after only a few minutes of playing.

I've Backed up and then restored, rebuilt the database, checked for dust bunnies and made sure the vents are clear (it's in the open now) and formatted the hard disk, all to no avail. All cables are plugged in, blu-ray film playback is fine, but on games the screen completely freezes, although game music will continue to play. The only way to gain functionality again is a complete rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the processor and GPU are overheating. The old "fat" PS3 at least had problems with the thermal paste. It was applied mechanically and the result is rather bad. There are countless tutorials on the web that explain how to open your PS3 and clean the old thermal paste in order to apply new. Alternatively you can go to some repair shop and have them do it for you. This should most likely stabilize your system and get it crash free again.

Comment: These links might help you: http://www.hometheatershack.com/forums/playstation/28605-ps3-maintenance-series-changing-thermal-paste.html

http://llamma.com/PS3/repair/PS3_disassembly_tutorial.htm

Keep in mind that your hardware revision can differ. Mine, also a "fatty", was quite a bit easier in some ways with the screws than those photos and videos show. If you need to, record where the screws came from, take digital photos, whatever you need to be able to put it back together. And make sure to use proper cleaning alcohol (no perfume or added oils).

Answer (score 0):

Does it emulate ps2 or psx games ? If so, have you tried to play those ?. Perhaps you can't play Ps3 games.

It happened me once, i could play anything but Ps3.

Try that one, perhaps you just can't play Ps3 games. If that's the case better take it to professional service.

Comment: Being unable to play the more resource-intensive games would likely boil down to overheating.